# INSERT into temporary table GTT very slow from PL/SQL

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, sql-tuning

I have a query that performs fantastic when executed from SQL.

It is a join between a table and a query. Both the tables are having close to 4 mn records.
There are bitmap indexes on the doc table that i am trying to provide hint on. The Explain plan does show they are helping the join well when i see from toad.

I have provided 2 other hints to see if they help as can be seen. One is for the Direct path APPEND and other to utilize the existing BTree index on pda.

When this query is run for substituted variables from SQL the results are instantaneous, but same query inside the procedure is taking 8 seconds or more.

Aside of the Procedure's plan which DBA hasnt yielded yet to, what are if any glaring misses that i may have you think? Thanks in advance.

```
 
     INSERT                                                           /*+ APPEND */
          INTO  tmp_search_gross_docs (document_id,
                                       last_name,
                                       first_name,
                                       person_doc_association_id,
                                       association_date)
       SELECT                 /*+INDEX(pda IDX_DOC_PDOC_DOCID ) USE_NL(pda doc) */
             pda.document_id,
              last_name,
              first_name,
              person_doc_association_id,
              association_date
         FROM   pda,
              (SELECT /*+INDEX_COMBINE(attr IDX_BMP_SEARCH_FN,IDX_BMP_SEARCH_LN)*/
                      document_id, last_name, first_name
                 FROM doc attr
                WHERE first_name LIKE l_first_name OR last_name LIKE l_last_name) doc
        WHERE pda.document_id = doc.document_id;
                         ) doc
                 WHERE pda.document_id = doc.document_id;
```

EXPLAIN Plan (from Toad for bind variables)

INSERT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 1,086,010  Bytes: 15,309,420  Cardinality: 364,510
    11 LOAD AS SELECT TMP_SEARCH_GROSS_DOCS
        10 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE PDA Cost: 3  Bytes: 20  Cardinality: 1
            9 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 1,086,010  Bytes: 15,309,420  Cardinality: 364,510
                7 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE ATTR Cost: 23,893  Bytes: 8,019,220  Cardinality: 364,510
                    6 BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS
                        5 BITMAP OR
                            2 BITMAP MERGE
                                1 BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (BITMAP) IDX_BMP_SEARCH_FN 
                            4 BITMAP MERGE
                                3 BITMAP INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (BITMAP) IDX_BMP_SEARCH_LN 
                8 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX IDX_PDA_EXP_DOC Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1

The cardinality 364,510 seems off as the table contains 3738562 rows and for a substituted values of the columns in WHERE the count is only 8892.

But again, this plan at least tells me that the right indexes are being used and runs very fast from the toad editor.

The actual plan from the PL/SQL is still not available.

Not sure if this adds some valuable info or not. But thought will edit nevertheless. Thanks

Comment: What else are you doing in that procedure?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but eventually it is building up a recordset that is then read by the application. I should point out that i did try the BULK COLLECT with a collection on the same SQL and that was the same performance too. Somehow feel the SELECT is not taking optimal path that it does when executed from editor..

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think inserting into GTT with append has any logic. i might be wrong but from what i know append bypass the buffer cache and writes directly to the file, it writes above the high water mark and does not allow querying until a commit is made. 
a GTT is not on regular data files - it's on the temp files and it's being truncated on commit (default settings).

I think that if you don't need to manipulate the data after the query consider returning a ref cursor to the application. it's basically the same thing - a lot of DAL layers are implemented this way.

if you still want the GTT , i would check my temp file allocation, both size and actual disks - your DBA might have put them on different devices.

Comment: +1 You're right to be skeptical of using GTT with append.  The advantage of a GTT is that it should always be cached; bypassing the cache for the first write probably won't help.  But it can still work, if the GTT is session-specific instead of transaction-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that you might look into.

1. Not relevant for GTT table. <del>Like you said, create the table in nologging more and when inserting use the insert append hint to do a direct path load.</del>
2. Also, there might be a misconception about the query speed if you are seeing the results from Toad. Softwares like toad automatically add hints to get the first 50/100/200 rows, hence the query might appear to run faster. Have you tried going to the last record (">" icon in the grid) and seeing how much time it takes to get the last row?
3. It is impossible to tune a query or even write good code without being able to see the plan. If it is a larger procedure, you can look at things like DBMS_PROFILER. IF you are sure this is the statement causing the issue, you can start with SQL trace or explain plan.

Comment: On #2, yes the query returns 600 odd rows for the parameters concerned that i am comparing the performance. I have gone to the last record in the results yes.

On 3. yes i have made sure this is the statement causing the delay. The plan from standalone SQL looks good which is how i tuned and took it to the procedure. No rights to run Trace either nor the actual execution plan of the procedure is yet available. Thanks for the reiterating the points though.

Answer (score 0):

[Adaptive cursor sharing does not apply to LIKE predicates.](http://optimizermagic.blogspot.com/2007/12/why-are-there-more-cursors-in-11g-for.html)

If your procedure was first executed with a parameter such as `%`, Oracle cannot use certain index access methods for the predicate.  Oracle could not obey your hint, and built a plan that was pretty good for `%` but horrible for everything else.

One possible solution is to force Oracle to always hard-parse your query.  I've used this solution, as explained by Dion Cho in 
[this OTN thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=854605):

```
dbms_stats.set_table_stats('schema','DOC',num_rows=>null,no_invalidate=>false);
```

Hard-parsing will use extra CPU resources, but hopefully a better plan will more than make up for the difference.  This solution will cause other, unrelated queries, to require a hard-parse.  You may want to look at some other solutions mentioned in the referenced thread.

Also, your [INDEX_COMBINE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#BABHJBAJ) hint may not be correct.  There should not be a comma between the indexes.  However, the hint syntax is poorly documented, and the hint parser will often work "partially".  Your hint is probably evaluated as the equivalant of 
`/*+INDEX_COMBINE(attr)*/`, which may or may not work the way you want it to.  You'll never know without the plans.

There are good reasons to avoid hints, especially if you don't have convenient access to the explain plans.

Comment: I did confirm that the hints are making the indexes to be used, so the syntax definitely is fine. I am still trying to study your other comment about setting hard-parse on. How to turn that off if at all?

Given that in that post the danger of "library cache contention" is mentioned.

Comment: You probably don't need to worry about the library cache.  If the query takes 8 seconds to run then it's probably not running very often.  Run `select count(*) from gv$sql;` and compare that with the number of distinct queries your procedure would produce if it always hard-parses.  Also, I'm still skeptical that the hints are working.  I think this is a case where the explain plan you're seeing is *not* the same as the real execution plan.  I'm not sure why you're having problems getting the actual plan, it should be easy to get.